# Caldroid, ActionBarSherlock and Maven

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, caldroid

I am trying to use [Caldroid](http://github.com/thomasdao/Caldroid) inside my simple HelloWorld application which previously included `ActionBarSherlock` under a Maven managed structure.

As I need to use a support package for ABS and Caldroid, I want Caldroid to use the same one. Currently, it is the latest: `support-v4-r7.jar`

However, in Eclipse I get a fail in `getChildFragmentManager()` saying the method is undefined (???) in `CaldroidFragment`. Therefore, I can't continue.

Also, I don't know if I should port every class of Caldroid to extend ABS classes in order to be used correctly. For instance:

```
public class CaldroidFragment extends DialogFragment    
to
public class CaldroidFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment
```

Any idea to integrate them?

Comment: Well, I don´t know how but the fact is that I saw the calendar embedded in my ABS-HelloWorld App. However, afterwards I cleaned, rebuilt and so on...and I couldn´t get it again. The fact is that the Google provided jar doesn´t contain the symbol getChildFragmentManager inside its app.Fragment class. Also, I didn´t need to port any class to be embedded in my SherlockFragmentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I just now figured out how to make Caldroid work along with ActionbarSherlock (without any errors).

1. Import ActionbarSherlock Library and Caldroid Library.
2. Then delete the **support v4 jar** from the **libs folder of ActionbarSherlock**
3. Add **caldroid as a dependency to ActionbarSherlock**.
4. Add ActionbarSherlock as a dependency to your app.

Now, everything will work without any errors !